# Patching required functionalities in IE7 for SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I'm getting this error when trying to access the page in Internet Explorer 7.

> "The required functionalities are not supported by your browser.
>   Please make sure you are using IE 8 or above, or other modern browser.
>   Please make sure the 'X-UA-Compatible' meta tag is set to be 'IE=8' or
>   above. (page.aspx?firstRedirect=1)"

I know that SP2013, does not support IE7 out of the box, but I need to make some features work. However this error message is not helpful, I need to know what features to patch and I get no stacktrace or anything else pointing me in the right direction.

The `X-UA-Compatible` is `IE=edge,chrome=1`. So it's not really a problem with the meta tag, but the browser.

How can I find the source of this error? How do I know what functionalities it's talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fired up Google Chrome DevTools and did a global search in Sources for this string.

It worked wonders, even if the error did not occur in Chrome.

Turns out it's `SP.RequestExecutor.$n` and `SP.RequestExecutor.$1N` that checks for `window.postMessage`, `window.JSON`, `window.Uint8Array` and some other things.

If these things are'nt defined it will `throw SP.RequestExecutorUtility.$s();`.

To avoid this I patch all the missing API's, making them return a more specific error.
In the case of `window.JSON` I included `JSON2`.